# Are escape pods capable of warp?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager, warp

In Voyager's [Year of Hell, Part I](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Year_of_Hell_%28episode%29), Chakotay suggests abandoning a very damaged Voyager and, using shuttles and escape pods, rendezvousing on the other side of [Krenim](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Krenim) space.

[image: Voyager escape pod]

Assuming Krenim space is about 15,000 light years across ([5,000 parsecs](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Krenim) as per Memory Alpha), it would take many thousands of years to travel that far at less-than-light speeds.

So, **do escape pods possess warp engines or other means of traveling FTL?**

Comment: Despite this, it is my sense that the whole warp system is fairly bulky, requiring a lot of "plumbing" so a plausible argument is that an escape pod is to small to have its own warp drive. I could see a temporary warp field supplied by the host ship with a fairly short half-life, probably not lasting long enough to do any sort of interstellar traveling which would seem sufficient to me anyway -- they are emergency vehicles used to reach a nearby target.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, escape pods are capable of warp. This was established in the Next Generation episode [Angel One](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angel_One) ([Memory Alpha](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Angel_One_%28episode%29)).

From [Memory Alpha](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Escape_pod):

> Escape pods, also known as rescue pods, of the Odin were capable of traveling at warp 1 for extended periods. It took them 5 months and 14 days to reach the nearest inhabited planet Angel I in 2357. (TNG: "Angel One")

Comment: Though if you really need to get someone somewhere fast, a [Class 8 Probe](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Class_8_probe) is capable of warp 9, though it's probably a lot less comfortable.

Comment: It was also detailed in the Tech Manual for the Galaxy class starships.

Answer (score 0):

Top answer is incorrect. They specifically say in Angel One  (TNG) that Odin's escape pods are "sub-light" for short periods. Sub-light meaning they can go just UNDER light speed, and therefore under warp. That's why it took them months to get to nearest habitable planet.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Indeed it appears that the [Escape Pod article on Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Escape_pod) has been changed since the previous answer was posted.  Of course it's possible that *Voyager's* pod are more capable...